# Is node.js executes just one context at the time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, ecmascript-6, nonblocking

Is Node.js execute just one context at the time or a single code instruction regardless of the context ?

In the case of some two non-blocking IO operations are finished and their callbacks are invoked, will they run concurrently or the Node.js will execute the first callback completely then execute the second one after that ?

Is it better to make the callback functions simple and shorter ? Will that improve the concurrency ?

Comment: Every turn of the event loop is run-to-completion. There won't be any callbacks interspersed between arbitrary instructions.

Comment: invoked callbacks on completion of IO operations will be executed sequentially, not concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

node.js is an EDA (event driven architecture) and as such is by design non-concurrent for the application code. This doesn't mean there aren't any concurrent threads. In fact the I/O is performed on concurrent threads, but their data is put on a queue which inherently serializes the I/O messages. This way, parallelism is serialized. There's no way you notice concurrency in your application code. Think about it as if you have only one thread and you cannot "jump" or "interleave" code execution at all.

If you experience a flood of I/O messages quicker processing surely will help. Quick callback functions means you can handle more in less time, avoiding congestion on the I/O queue. That's why you should never block.

Comment: Worst case scenario is the OP has to add a FIFO buffer to hold completed threads, say 8 levels deep or more. Now you have a 'burst' mode to move lots of data in packets. Penalty is the the downstream code must be able to parse/handle an onslaught of data with no blocking. Advantage is the parsing time allows for parallel processing of data that is NOT co-dependent.